# using an http request to update google spreadsheet

Tags: python, google-apps-script, web-applications, authorization, http-status-code-401

Trying to set up a spreadsheet to take in data via an http post. To test it, I set up a simple python script to just send an http request. I dont want to use a specific google api on python or somewhere else, because I want some other people to be able to simply send a request how they would like. So, In my google script I just have:

```
function doPost(e){
   sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   range = sheet.getRange(1, 1)
   ange.setValue(e.text)
}
```

In python I simply have:

```
import requests

if __name__== "__main__":
    params = {'Authorization': "Bearer [token]",
              'contentType': 'application/json',
              'text': "is working?"}
    r = requests.post("https://script.google.com/macros/s/[uniquekey]/exec", params)
    print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

All I get is

> "401 Unauthorized"

I've also tried sending this over python as well as running JS in a webserver and through chrome (which i guessed raised security issues). everything gave me the same response. I'm sure I'm just not authorizing properly, but I havent been able to find the correct way to do it. thanks in advance. I'm sure theres some other issues too, but I cant seem to even get access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification?

### Modified script:

In this modified script supposes as follows.

- Web Apps is deployed as

  - **Execute the app as** is `Me`
  - **Who has access to the app** is `Only myself` or `Anyone`
- Your access token can be used for accessing to your Web Apps.
  If your access token cannot be used for it, please try to set the Web Apps as follows.
      - **Execute the app as** is `Me`
      - **Who has access to the app** is `Anyone, even anonymous`
      - In this setting, you can access to Web Apps without the access token.

#### Python:

```
import requests

if __name__== "__main__":
    params = {
        'text': "is working?",
    }
    headers = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer [token]",
    }
    r = requests.post("https://script.google.com/macros/s/[uniquekey]/exec", data=params, headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

Note:

- Please put the access token to the header.

#### Google Apps Script:

When you modified your script, **please redeploy as new version.** By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps.

```
function doPost(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange(1, 1);
  range.setValue(e.parameter.text);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done.");
}
```

Note:

- By returning `ContentService.createTextOutput()`, Web Apps returns the status code of 200.
- You can retrieve the value of `'text': "is working?"` as `e.parameter.text`.
- When you use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()`, the value of `e.parameter.text` is put to the 1st page of Spreadsheet.

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service)

In my environment, I could confirm that this modification worked. But if in your environment, this modified scripts didn't work, I'm sorry.

Comment: thank you very much. changing the setting to "even anonymous" did work. I am still doing something wrong with the authorization token. I probably just dont fully know how to set that up through the google api auth system but this gets me on my way to setting up the sheet as I need to and I can work on the auth stuff later. thanks again.

Comment: @Bastiat Thank you for replying. I'm glad a part of your issue was resolved. About the authorization, for example, is this quickstart useful for you? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python In this script, OAuth2 process is used.

Comment: were it just a project on my part, yea, I would just be using that. I had hoped to be able to do this just via standard requests without the library because I was just using python for testing while the actual use case would be push requests sent from a powershell environment. So I was trying to avoid those kinds of dependent libraries. Maybe that was a valid goal, maybe not.